# Bimodal Posteriors in Bayesian Non-linear Regression

Tags: bayesian, model, nonlinear-regression

I will preamble by saying thank for reading this, and that any commenter should feel free to criticise any aspect of this modelling specification or workflow you deem naive or uninformed.

I am simulating two groups from this double sigmoid curve process:

$$ y = \frac{y_{\text{mid}}}{1 + e^{-(a \cdot \text{time} + b)}} + \frac{y_{\text{max}}}{1 + e^{-(c \cdot \text{time} + d)}}, \quad 0 \leq y \leq 100, \quad \text{time} \in [0, 300]
$$

Using the following code in brms:

```r
sw_dbl_log <- function(a, b, c, d, time){
  ((50)/(1+exp(-a*Time + b)))+((50)/(1+exp(-c*Time + d)))
}

nn = 300
Raw<- tibble(n = 1:(nn*2),
              Group = rep(c("Control", "Experimental"), each = nn),
              a = c(rnorm(nn, 0.1, 0.01),
                    rnorm(nn, 0.1,  0.01)),
              b = c(rnorm(nn, 5,  0.01),
                    rnorm(nn, 5,  0.01)),
              c = c(rnorm(nn, 0.1, 0.01),
                    rnorm(nn, 0.1, 0.002)),
              d = c(rnorm(nn, 5, 0.01),
                    rnorm(nn, 25, 0.01))
) %>% 
  tidyr::expand(nesting(n,Group, a, b, c, d),
                Time = seq(0, 300, by = 10)) %>% 
  mutate(y = sw_dbl_log(a, b, c, d, Time))
```

As expected, this produces Gaussian distributions for each Group’s parameters (a:d), with the Control group’s time series resembling a single sigmoid with one growth phase. The Experimental group’s time series has two phases of growth, as intended. I am leveraging this specification because each parameter gives a clearly interpretable output, that is, a and c represent growth rates and b represents the time point of inflexion for each of the growth phases.

[image]

My fitting procedure is as follows :

```r
formula <- bf(y ~ (50/(1+exp(-a*Time + b))) + (50/(1+exp(-c*Time + d))), 
              a + b + c + d ~ 0 + Group,
              set_rescor(FALSE),
              nl = TRUE)

prior1 <- c(
  prior(normal(0.1, 0.1), nlpar = "a", lb = 0),
  prior(normal(5, 2), nlpar = "b", lb = 0, ub = 10),
  prior(normal(0.1, 0.1), nlpar = "c",lb = 0),
  prior(normal(25, 5), nlpar = "d", coef = "GroupExperimental"),
  prior(normal(5, 2), nlpar = "d", coef = "GroupControl")
)

fit <- brm(formula, 
           data = Raw, 
           prior = prior1,
           control = list(adapt_delta = 0.95, max_treedepth = 15),
           iter = 10000,
           warmup = 5000,
           cores = 3, 
           chains = 3)
```

I’ve omitted prior fitting and predictive checks from the code above, but visual inspection looks good.

This issue I am currently having is that the model fit is poor, namely, the Rhat and ESS numbers are too low, and it’s principally due to bimodality in the posterior distribution of the parameters for either one of the groups, sometimes Control and sometimes Experimental, that is causing the chains not to converge. So for some fits, any or all of the posterior distributions for a,b,c,d by Group (e.g "b_a_GroupExperimental") will be bimodal.

I cannot seem to define why the model is fitting poorly and causing this bimodality. My first guess is that the priors are causing issues, but, as per my naïve understanding, the priors are specified pretty tightly around the original simulation distributions so I cannot see why they might be causing the problem. I must admit that this conclusion might expose my ignorance on the topic which is fueling my inability to fix the fit issues.

Should I change the priors, the model, stipulate init values or simply run for more iterations? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: As an update, here are the posteriors for each parameter by Group.

Also, if I made the Control group's simulation values for b and d different, and thus make the time series represent a double sigmoid instead of a single sigmoid, their posteriors return as expected. For example, if $$ a_{C} = 0.1, b_{C} = 5, c_{C} = 0.1, d_{C} = 20 $$ , those values match the mean of the posteriors and the chains mix as expected. However, the Experimental group's remain bimodal and the chains do not mix.

[image]

Comment: I've formatted the code for readability. The correct way to format code is to enclose it between three backticks, not between <code> HTML tags. See also [Markdown Editing Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Why does the control group have two components? I don't think these are identifiable, at least not in the simulation presented. Instead `(2*(50)/(1+exp(-a*Time + b)))` may be a more reasonable model for `E(Y)` in the control group.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and code corrections @dipetkov. 

I understand the parsimony of collapsing the Control group into a single sigmoid; however, this would remove two inferential necessities: 1. Comparing parameters c and d between groups, and 2. Comparing between parameters a/c or b/d within a group. These comparisons are required for the research questions that are being tested.

Comment: Also, does collapsing the parameters for the Control group affect the fitting of the model? I ask since the model does not have any information about the simulation parameter values but only Y, Group, and Time values where collapsing would leave these unaffected.

Comment: PS: I noticed that you cross-posted this question; here it is on the Stan discourse forum where it got essentially the same answer: [Issues with bimodality in parameter posterior distributions of non-linear time series](https://discourse.mc-stan.org/t/issues-with-bimodality-in-parameter-posterior-distributions-of-non-linear-time-series/34032). Cross-posting is discouraged as it's often leads to waste of time -- what's the purpose of getting the same answer twice? But if you must do it, it's best to be clear in your question that you've cross-posted and where.

Comment: Apologies, I did not realise this was a faux pas and will ensure I note any cross-posting in the future. I did not assume that I would receive the same answer twice. Instead, I assumed that I would not receive an answer on the Stan discourse forum, given it had been 5 days already. Critically, whilst you and the other commenter did mention label switching, you provided distinct solutions to the problem, so no time was wasted there.

Comment: I didn't pay attention that you waited for a week on the Stan discourse and I made a wrong assumption that you posted at both forums at the same time. I apologize. (And your question is interesting and well written in any case.)

Comment: Thanks @dipetkov, both for guidance in this issue and for appreciating my point of view with regard to my cross-posting.

As an update, since label switching seems to be an issue I cannot solve with the current model, I've moved to a more flexible approach using longitudinal Gaussian process regression through the [lgpr](https://jtimonen.github.io/lgpr-usage/reference/lgpr-package.html) r package. Thanks again for you help and patience.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR. The bimodality is due to label switching. Just as a two-component normal mixture has a bimodal posterior, so does the this mixture of two sigmoid components: swapping the a/b and c/d parameter pairs (so the "first" component has parameters c/d and the "second" one parameters a/b) results in the same likelihood. One solution is to impose an ordering constraint.

See also this in-depth tutorial by Michael Betancourt: [Identifying Bayesian Mixture Models](https://mc-stan.org/users/documentation/case-studies/identifying_mixture_models.html).

---

I found this question interesting. So in writing an answer I proceed to considerably modify the simulation and to completely ignore the model specified by the OP. Nevertheless, I do fit a non-linear Bayesian model for the sum of two sigmoid components and the model converges reasonably well. So hopefully my answer is useful to the OP.

#### The simulation

Without loss of generality, I scale the time $X$ and the outcome $Y$ to the [0, 1] range. I also parametrize the sigmoid curve as a location-scale family: instead of $\operatorname{sigmoid}(ax + b)$ I use $\operatorname{sigmoid}((x - \text{loc}) / \text{scale})$.

Here are some examples of one- and two-sigmoid growth curves.

[image]

For $\operatorname{sigmoid}((x-\text{loc})/\text{scale})$, the location parameter is the $x$ value at which the function is equal to 0.5 and the scale parameter determines the steepness at $x = \text{loc}$.

Caveat: I suspect it is intended that the growth process starts at $(X=0, Y=0)$ and ends at $(X=1, Y=1)$. However, the sigmoid function is defined on the real line and its return value might be greater than 0 at $x=0$ and less than 1 at $x=1$. To constrain the sigmoid to start at ≈ 0 and end at ≈ 1 for $x\in[0,1]$ we have to make the function steep enough. This implies that location and scale are correlated; the closer the location is to the boundary (0 or 1), the stronger the correlation.

I don't explicitly model the correlation between location and scale. As long as the location is within the interior — say between 0.1 and 0.9 — both parameters seems to be reliably estimated.

#### The model

I write a Stan model for a mixture of two sigmoid components and I fit the model twice, first to simulated experimental data and then to simulated control data.

Aside: Little information is lost in fitting two smaller models to half of the data rather than one big to all of the data. Even in the OP's original formulation, the two groups have their own sigmoid parameters and the only shared parameter is the measurement error, $\sigma$, which is negligible in this simulation.

An important part of this Stan model is that the two location parameters are ordered: `loc1 < loc2`. This constraint breaks the symmetry between the two equally valid orderings of the two locations and thus removes one mode of the bimodal posterior. I use Stan's handy [`ordered`](https://mc-stan.org/docs/reference-manual/vector-and-matrix-data-types.html#ordered-vectors) vector type.

```
parameters {
  ordered[2] locations;
  real<lower=0> scale1;
  real<lower=0> scale2;
}
transformed parameters {
  real loc1 = locations[1];
  real loc2 = locations[2];

  // inv_logit() is the sigmoid function.
  real mu = (
    0.5 * inv_logit((X - loc1) / scale1) +
    0.5 * inv_logit((X - loc2) / scale2)
  );
}
```

Note: The R code to reproduce the analysis, together with the complete Stan model, is attached at the end.

And here is a summary the results. First, the posterior growth curves (in red) under the two conditions, Experimental and Control. Also shown (in light grey) is the simulated data.

[image]

And finally the summaries of the two fitted models:

```r
# Experimental group
#>   variable    mean  median       sd      mad      q5     q95  rhat ess_bulk
#> 1 loc1     0.200   0.200   0.0143   0.0143   0.177   0.225   1.00     1911.
#> 2 loc2     0.800   0.800   0.0141   0.0142   0.777   0.823   1.00     2537.
#> 3 scale1   0.0495  0.0495  0.00142  0.00136  0.0471  0.0519  1.00     2792.
#> 4 scale2   0.0508  0.0508  0.00148  0.00149  0.0484  0.0533  1.01     3219.
#> 5 sigma    0.00956 0.00956 0.000178 0.000180 0.00928 0.00987 0.999    2136.

# Control group
#>   variable    mean  median       sd      mad      q5    q95  rhat ess_bulk
#> 1 loc1     0.191   0.191   0.0123   0.0123   0.171   0.210   1.00   2535. 
#> 2 loc2     0.207   0.207   0.0115   0.0110   0.188   0.227   1.00   2515. 
#> 3 scale1   0.0492  0.0492  0.00232  0.00237  0.0454  0.0530  1.07     38.0
#> 4 scale2   0.0481  0.0481  0.00226  0.00234  0.0446  0.0519  1.07     34.0
#> 5 sigma    0.00992 0.00992 0.000193 0.000190 0.00961 0.0102  1.00   2490.
```

The fit to the Experimental data is great while there are some issues with the fit to the Control data (two Rhat's of 1.07). Maybe this can be improved with stronger priors? Or even better — for modeling the simulated data at least — is to fit a single sigmoid component for Control.

---

```r
library("truncnorm")
library("tidybayes")
library("posterior")
library("cmdstanr")
library("tidyverse")

set.seed(1234)

# sigmoid = inverse logit = plogis
sigmoid <- function(x) {
  plogis(x) # 1 / (1 + exp(-x))
}
growth_curve <- function(x, loc1, scale1, loc2, scale2) {
  0.5 * sigmoid((x - loc1) / scale1) + 0.5 * sigmoid((x - loc2) / scale2)
}

N <- 50 # curves per group

sim_df <-
  tibble(
    Curve = rep(1:N, times = 2),
    Group = rep(c("Control", "Treatment"), each = N),
    a = c(
      rnorm(N, mean = 0.2, sd = 0.01),
      rnorm(N, mean = 0.2, sd = 0.01)
    ),
    b = c(
      rtruncnorm(N, mean = 0.05, sd = 0.01, a = 0),
      rtruncnorm(N, mean = 0.05, sd = 0.01, a = 0)
    ),
    c = c(
      rnorm(N, mean = 0.2, sd = 0.01),
      rnorm(N, mean = 0.8, sd = 0.01)
    ),
    d = c(
      rtruncnorm(N, mean = 0.05, sd = 0.01, a = 0),
      rtruncnorm(N, mean = 0.05, sd = 0.01, a = 0)
    )
  ) %>%
  expand(
    nesting(Curve, Group, a, b, c, d),
    Time = seq(0, 1, length = 31)
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    Ey = growth_curve(Time, a, b, c, d),
    Y = rnorm(n(), mean = Ey, sd = 0.01)
  )

# sim_df <- sim_df %>% filter(Group == "Control")
sim_df <- sim_df %>% filter(Group == "Treatment")

sim_data <- list(
  N = nrow(sim_df),
  K = max(sim_df$Curve),
  Y = sim_df$Y,
  X = sim_df$Time,
  I = sim_df$Curve,
  A = distinct(sim_df, Curve, a, b, c, d)$a,
  B = distinct(sim_df, Curve, a, b, c, d)$b,
  C = distinct(sim_df, Curve, a, b, c, d)$c,
  D = distinct(sim_df, Curve, a, b, c, d)$d
)

code <- "
data {
  int N;
  int K;
  array[N] int I;
  vector[N] Y;
  vector[N] X;
  vector[K] A;
  vector[K] B;
  vector[K] C;
  vector[K] D;
}
parameters {
  ordered[2] locations;
  real<lower=0> scale1;
  real<lower=0> scale2;

  vector[K] nlp_a;
  vector[K] nlp_c;
  vector<lower=0>[K] nlp_b;
  vector<lower=0>[K] nlp_d;

  real<lower=0> sigma;  // dispersion parameter
}
transformed parameters {
  real loc1 = locations[1];
  real loc2 = locations[2];

  vector[N] mu = (
    0.5 * inv_logit((X - nlp_a[I]) ./ nlp_b[I]) +
    0.5 * inv_logit((X - nlp_c[I]) ./ nlp_d[I])
  );
}
model {
  nlp_a ~ normal(loc1, 0.1);
  nlp_c ~ normal(loc2, 0.1);
  nlp_b ~ normal(scale1, 0.01);
  nlp_d ~ normal(scale2, 0.01);
  sigma ~ normal(0, 1);
  
  Y ~ normal(mu, sigma);
}
"

model <- cmdstan_model(
  write_stan_file(code)
)
init <- list(
  locations = c(0.2, 0.8),
  scale1 = 0.05,
  scale2 = 0.05,
  sigma = 0.01
)
fit <- model$sample(
  data = sim_data,
  init = list(init, init),
  chains = 2,
  parallel_chains = 2
)
fit$diagnostic_summary()

draws <- as_draws_df(fit)
draws <- subset_draws(draws, c("loc1", "loc2", "scale1", "scale2", "sigma"))
summarise_draws(draws)

draws %>%
  expand(
    nesting(.chain, .iteration, .draw, loc1, scale1, loc2, scale2),
    Time = seq(0, 1, length = 31)
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    Y = growth_curve(Time, loc1, scale1, loc2, scale2)
  ) %>%
  ggplot(
    aes(x = Time, y = Y)
  ) +
  geom_line(
    aes(Time, Y, group = interaction(Group, Curve)),
    alpha = 0.1,
    data = sim_df
  ) +
  stat_lineribbon(color = "#67000D") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Reds") +
  theme(
    legend.position = "none"
  )
```

Comment: This is provocative and useful, particularly by introducing an ordering constraint. Thanks for taking the time to test it and lay out your ideas here.

Am I right in assuming you fit these in separate models, as you filter one group into "sim_df" and fit it? Can I compare the posteriors of each model without impacting pooling, partial dependencies etc?

Comment: You are welcome. There is little pooling in the brms model also: the only parameter that the groups share is the error variance sigma. So I expect -- but haven't tried -- to get the same posteriors with a "big" Stan model.

Comment: It would be easy to try this out: You need to have two sets of inputs and two sets of parameters. Use a subscript like `_1` and `_2` to distinguish the two sets of data & parameters. The likelihood would be something like `Y_1 ~ normal(mu_1, sigma); Y_2 ~ normal(mu_2, sigma);`. Then you can use the tools in the Stan ecosystem to evaluate the results, etc.

Comment: This seems simple enough, are there any dangers in comparing the groups inferentially using their posteriors? For example, looking at the difference in the curves over time using BFs, ROPE etc?

Comment: It should be fine. Keep in mind the label switching phenomenon when you decide what parameters you want to compare. (Basically, which component is designated a/b vs c/d is arbitrary. With the ordering one component occurs "earlier", the other "later".) Bayes Factors have some conceptual issues (Andrew Gelman has written about those on his blog. Or see the Bayesian Data Analysis book.) ROPE would be a more principled Bayesian approach.

Comment: Ok so now I think I understand why you keep suggesting modelling the Control group as a single sigmoid since you are saying that we could take the posteriors from that model and compare them to the double sigmoid of the Experimental group using ROPE etc. Is this correct?

Also, I wholeheartedly agree with the conceptual issues of BF and place ROPE, as part of the SeXiT framework, as my primary inferential indicator. Thanks for validating that here also.

Comment: I noticed that in the simulation the Control group clearly has one sigmoid (which it shares with the Experimental group). The more realistic the simulation, the better, so I wondered whether it's known that the controls have one growth stage. If yes, it's better to incorporate this knowledge into the model, rather than fit a two-component model and do hypothesis testing on its parameters.

Comment: Incorporating the single growth phase into the model makes sense to me; however, the foreign choice prior to this conversation was that I could analyse their differences using posteriors derived from separate regression models.